# Python dictionary Iterate the right way

Tags: python, dictionary, neo4j, iterator

I need to save nodes by iterating Product Pages first. The values i need to store and put it in a Node for Neo4J Graph Database. This is a Example Node:

I Need to save it as this:

```
n = Node('Component', 'CPU',
         AantalCores=AantalCores,
         CPUSSpecNumber=CPUSSpecNumber,
         Snelheid=Snelheid,
         MaximaleTurboFrequentie=MaximaleTurboFrequentie,
         GeheugenSpecificatie=GeheugenSpecificatie,
         BusSnelheid=BusSnelheid,
         Procestechnologie=Procestechnologie,
         ThermalDesignPower=ThermalDesignPower,
         GeïntegreerdeGraphics=GeïntegreerdeGraphics,
         Gpu=Gpu,
         NominaleSnelheidVideochip=NominaleSnelheidVideochip,
         MaximaleSnelheidVideochip=MaximaleSnelheidVideochip,
         CPUCacheLevel1=CPUCacheLevel1,
         CPUCacheLevel2=CPUCacheLevel2,
         CPUCacheLevel3=CPUCacheLevel3,
         Threads=Threads,
         Virtualisatie=Virtualisatie,
         VirtualisatieType=VirtualisatieType,
         CPUMultiplier=CPUMultiplier,
         CPUstepping=CPUstepping,
         CPUInstructieset=CPUInstructieset,
         TypeKoeling=TypeKoeling)
```

I have this CODE:

```
    if componentTitle == 'Processoren':
        properties = {'AantalCores': 'NULL',
                      'CPUSSpecNumber': 'NULL',
                      'Snelheid': 'NULL',
                      'MaximaleTurboFrequentie': 'NULL',
                      'GeheugenSpecificatie': 'NULL',
                      'BusSnelheid': 'NULL',
                      'Procestechnologie': 'NULL',
                      'ThermalDesignPower': 'NULL',
                      'GeïntegreerdeGraphics': 'NULL',
                      'Gpu': 'NULL',
                      'NominaleSnelheidVideochip': 'NULL',
                      'MaximaleSnelheidVideochip': 'NULL',
                      'CPUCacheLevel1': 'NULL',
                      'CPUCacheLevel2': 'NULL',
                      'CPUCacheLevel3': 'NULL',
                      'Threads': 'NULL',
                      'Virtualisatie': 'NULL',
                      'VirtualisatieType': 'NULL',
                      'CPUMultiplier': 'NULL',
                      'CPUstepping': 'NULL',
                      'CPUInstructieset': 'NULL',
                      'TypeKoeling': 'NULL'}

        if spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Processorkernen':
            properties['AantalCores'] = value.text.strip()
        elif spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Kloksnelheid':
            properties['Snelheid'] = value.text.strip()
        elif spec.get_text(strip=True) == 'Threads':
            properties['Threads'] = value.text.strip()
```

AND I NEED TO ITERATE THROUGH THE keys/values OF properties AND SAVE IT HERE:

```
for key in range(0, len(properties)):
    product = Node("Component", 'CPU', key=properties[key])
```

So it should be like this:

```
product = Node("Component", 'CPU',
               AantalCores='Quad-Core',
               CPUSSpecNumber= 'NULL',
               Snelheid= '3400 MHz',
               MaximaleTurboFrequentie= 'NULL',
               GeheugenSpecificatie= 'NULL',
               BusSnelheid= 'NULL',
               Procestechnologie= 'NULL',
               ThermalDesignPower= 'NULL',
               GeïntegreerdeGraphics= 'NULL',
               Gpu= 'NULL',
               NominaleSnelheidVideochip= 'NULL',
               MaximaleSnelheidVideochip= 'NULL',
               CPUCacheLevel1= 'NULL',
               CPUCacheLevel2= 'NULL',
               'CPUCacheLevel3': 'NULL',
               'Threads': '8',
               'Virtualisatie': 'NULL',
               'VirtualisatieType': 'NULL',
               'CPUMultiplier': 'NULL',
               CPUstepping= 'NULL',
               CPUInstructieset= 'NULL',
               TypeKoeling= 'NULL'
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @PeterWood, at the very least the fact that iterating `key` over a range of `int`s will be no use at all (since those `int`s can't be used to index into the `properties` `dict`!-).

Answer (score 1):

The `properties` `dict` -- like any `dict` -- has **NO** fixed order.  If you don't care about the order, then:

```
product = Node('Component', 'CPU', **properties)
```

will work as specified.  If you **do** care about the order, you need to specify that **somehow** -- e.g with a list, rather than a dict!

Comment: Or with an collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @RickTeachey, except that when used as `**`, the order will be lost anyway!-)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Having a OBJECT

class productNode():

```
def nodeCPU(self, AantalCores, CPUSSpecNumber, Snelheid, MaximaleTurboFrequentie, GeheugenSpecificatie, BusSnelheid, Procestechnologie, ThermalDesignPower, GeïntegreerdeGraphics, Gpu, NominaleSnelheidVideochip, MaximaleSnelheidVideochip, CPUCacheLevel1, CPUCacheLevel2, CPUCacheLevel3, Threads, Virtualisatie, VirtualisatieType, CPUMultiplier, CPUstepping, CPUInstructieset, TypeKoeling):
    n = Node('Component', 'CPU', AantalCores=AantalCores, CPUSSpecNumber=CPUSSpecNumber, Snelheid=Snelheid, MaximaleTurboFrequentie=MaximaleTurboFrequentie, GeheugenSpecificatie=GeheugenSpecificatie, BusSnelheid=BusSnelheid, Procestechnologie=Procestechnologie, ThermalDesignPower=ThermalDesignPower, GeïntegreerdeGraphics=GeïntegreerdeGraphics, Gpu=Gpu, NominaleSnelheidVideochip=NominaleSnelheidVideochip, MaximaleSnelheidVideochip=MaximaleSnelheidVideochip, CPUCacheLevel1=CPUCacheLevel1, CPUCacheLevel2=CPUCacheLevel2, CPUCacheLevel3=CPUCacheLevel3, Threads=Threads, Virtualisatie=Virtualisatie, VirtualisatieType=VirtualisatieType, CPUMultiplier=CPUMultiplier, CPUstepping=CPUstepping, CPUInstructieset=CPUInstructieset, TypeKoeling=TypeKoeling)
    return n
```

and send all the values like this:

```
        product = productNode.nodeCPU('CPU', p['AantalCores'],p['CPUSSpecNumber'],p['Snelheid'],p['MaximaleTurboFrequentie'],p['GeheugenSpecificatie'] ......
```

It worked :)

Comment: Yes, but the order so carefully preserved in the `def` and its call is then destroyed when `Node` is called with keyword parameters, so why bother vs the much more concise `**properties` in my answer?!